# displaying duplicate entry from database with php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display data from search function in database but unfortunately i get duplicate entries, can anyone check this and help me a little bit:

I am using this query and this php Code where **`startdate`** and **`enddate`** are from the *`members`* table, all the others data are from **`person`** table:

```
$query = "select * FROM person, members where fname= '$fname' AND lname = '$lname'";

for ($i=0; $i <$num_results; $i++)
  {
     $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
     echo '<p><strong>'.($i+1).'. Name: ';
     echo htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($row['fname']));
     echo '</strong><br />Surname: ';
     echo stripslashes($row['lname']);
     echo '<br />Board: ';
     echo stripslashes($row['board']);
     echo '<br />Department: ';
     echo stripslashes($row['departmentname']);
     echo '<br />Start Date: ';
     echo stripslashes($row['startdate']);
     echo '<br />End Date: ';
     echo stripslashes($row['enddate']);
     echo '</p>';
```

**This is what i get as output: So i want to be displayed only on person with name aa nd surname bb (not five times but only once).**

```
1. Name: aa
Surname: bb
Board: Secur
Department: Telec
Start Date: 2016-07-01
Edn Date: 2016-07-31

2. Name: aa
Surname: bb
Board: Secur
Department: Telec
Start Date: 2016-07-19
Edn Date: 2016-07-21
```

[after searching during the edit process the ID is not changing at all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4PTj.jpg)

```
<?php
function renderForm($personid, $personname, $personsurname, $error)
{
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Edit Record</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
// if there are any errors, display them
if ($error != '')
{
echo '<div style="padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red;">'.$error.'</div>';
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="personid" value="<?php echo $personid; ?>"/>
<div>
<p><strong>ID:</strong> <?php echo $personid; ?></p>
<strong>First Name: *</strong> <input type="text" name="personname" value="<?php echo $personname; ?>"/><br/>
<strong>Last Name: *</strong> <input type="text" name="personsurname" value="<?php echo $personsurname; ?>"/><br/>
<p>* Required</p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
// connect to the database

$host = "localhost"; 
$user = "kkoikm_kum"; 
$pass = "datgbhnkum"; 
$db = "koikm_kum";

// open connection 
$connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ("Unable to connect!"); 

// select database 
mysql_select_db($db) or die ("Unable to select database!");

// check if the form has been submitted. If it has, process the form and save it to the database
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
// confirm that the 'id' value is a valid integer before getting the form data
if (is_numeric($_POST['personid']))
{
// get form data, making sure it is valid
$personid = $_POST['personid'];
$personname = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['personname']));
$personsurname = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['personsurname']));

// check that firstname/lastname fields are both filled in
if ($personname == '' || $personsurname == '')

// generate error message
$error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';

//error, display form
renderForm($personid, $personname, $personsurname, $error);
}
else
{
// save the data to the database
mysql_query("UPDATE tblperson SET personname='$personname', personsurname='$personsurname' WHERE personid='$personid'")
or die(mysql_error());

// once saved, redirect back to the view page
header("Location: home.php");
}
}
else
{
// if the 'id' isn't valid, display an error
echo 'Error!';
}
}
else
// if the form hasn't been submitted, get the data from the db and display the form
{
// get the 'id' value from the URL (if it exists), making sure that it is valid (checing that it is numeric/larger than 0)
if (isset($_GET['personid']) && is_numeric($_GET['personid']) && $_GET['personid'] > 0)
{
// query db
$personid = $_GET['personid'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblperson WHERE personid=$personid")
or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

// check that the 'id' matches up with a row in the databse
if($row)
{
// get data from db
$personname = $row['personname'];
$personsurname = $row['personsurname'];

// show form
renderForm($personid, $personname, $personsurname, '');
}
else
// if no match, display result
{
echo "No results!";
}
}
else
// if the 'id' in the URL isn't valid, or if there is no 'id' value, display an error
{
echo 'Error!';
}
}
?>
```

I have modified this code but seems that i have made mistakes and i cant find the. after being able to edit the name and surname i will add other fields also.

Comment: Add `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: @Shrikant , Thank you man and yeah it works as you said. Thank you

Comment: That's great. Can you please then vote up and accept my answer? ;)

Comment: Yeah man sure, im in the biging of my project probably i will have a lot of questions

Comment: You should use a join condition. Something like `members.person_id = person.id`. Please post table definitions. Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE person` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE members`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming there is primary/unique key in your person table

```
$query = "select * FROM person, members where fname= '$fname' AND lname = '$lname' GROUP BY person.person_id";
```

Comment: Yeah there is a primary key but i dont what to display that, i will try. Thank

Comment: hi @Shrikant m Not exactly. I am trying t built a edit form right now, My search function is working fine but i cant get the edit form and php:

Comment: What's the problem you are facing?

Comment: Well, after searching im trying to edit name, surname department or date but everytime only the same id is editable i dont know why. I will modiffy the question peasle check it @Shrikant

Comment: I'm not able understand your code. You need to provide more details about what you have done, file names and all. I would suggest create another question and give proper file names and there coding, Also explain your execution flow and where exactly your are stuck. You can't edit your entire question after your previous problem is solved. Accept and up vote current answer and close this question and like I said create another question with proper details.